# URL rewrite confusion

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a htaccess file to help rewrite my  url of  ../players.php?first_name=Richard&last_name=Marston this gives me the url of ../Richard%20Marston, here is my .htaccess file contents

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ players.php?first_name=$1&last_name=$2

IndexIgnore *
```

can someone help and amend my current .htaccess file so it reads without the %20 and instead either with no gap such  as ../RichardMarston ... or with a - such as ../Richard-Marston for profile pages

Much appreciated

Comment: are you sure that rewrite rule does what you think it does? I think it would put everything in $1? your regex only has one matching group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one  for `Richard-Marston`

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)-([^/.]+)$ players.php?first_name=$1&last_name=$2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of separator between first name and last name. If you have only one rule, you can remove `players/`  in  rewrite rule:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^players/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ players.php?first_name=$1&last_name=$2

IndexIgnore *
```

It will rewrite URLs like `players/Richard/Marston`  to `players.php?first_name=Richard&last_name=Marston`.